Getting "Permission Error" while trying to pin a shortcut to the "start menu" with powerShell
I am trying to pin a shortcut from my desktop to the start menu but it's giving me a permission error even though I am running the powershell as an administrator.  I have tried different verbs such as "Open" and it works perfectly fine, yet it gives me this error on pinning to the start menu.
Below is the code I wrote:
$desktopPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
$shortcutName = "XAMPP Control Panel.lnk"  # Name of the shortcut
$shortcutPath = Join-Path $desktopPath $shortcutName

$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$Folder = $Shell.Namespace((Get-Item $shortcutPath).DirectoryName)
$Item = $Folder.ParseName((Get-Item $shortcutPath).Name)
$Item.Verbs() | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_.Name }
$Verb = $Item.Verbs() | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "&Pin to Start"}

if ($Verb) {
    $Verb.DoIt()
    Write-Output "Pinned."
} else {
    Write-Output "Not Pinned"
}

Here is an image of the error:

*EDIT:
I have tried this approach:
run> gpedit.msc >User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Start Menu and Taskbar. On the right-panel, double-click on the “Prevent users from customizing their Start Screen”> disabled
And after that, I restarted it to make sure the change was done, yet the result was the same.


(Old repeating Windows question) "started with 1909, even when trying to do it in graphical user interface you just don't get the option. Set the following gpo to disabled and it starts working:"
User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Start Menu and Taskbar. On the right-pane, double-click on the “Prevent users from customizing their Start Screen”

@iRon Thank you for your response. I tried what you proposed, but the result didn't change. I will update the question mentioning it.

Anyhow, I don't think there is anything wrong with your PowerShell script and therefore recommend you to check with the https://superuser.com/ site instead.

I use import-startlayout, at least for new users.

@js2010 I tried using it but no matter how much I try, I can't get it to work. Can you please tell me how to do it? When I import the .xml it works(It gets copied to the shell folder), but no changes to my start

It may only work in new profiles.

Try : if ($Verb.Count -ge 0) {.........  $Verb is not true/false.  It may be null.  The error is really being occurring on the line $Verb.Doit()
